# 2D Heat equation: inconsistent boundary and initial conditions

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I'm attempting to use NDSolve on a 2D boundary value problem with initial conditions. Upon running my code, I get the following message:

*"NDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: Boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent."*

After much head-scratching, I can't seem to find my mistake. It seems to me that my initial condition is consistent with my boundary conditions:

```
k = 1 / (5*(Pi^2));
soln = NDSolve[
  {
  (* PDE *)
  D[u[x, y, t], t] == k*(D[u[x, y, t], x, x] + D[u[x, y, t], y, y]),

  (* initial condition *)
  u[x, y, 0] == y + Cos[Pi*x] Sin[2*Pi*y],

  (* boundary conditions *)
  u[x, 0, t] == 0,
  u[x, 1, t] == 1,
  (D[u[x, y, t], x] /. x -> 0) == 0,
  (D[u[x, y, t], x] /. x -> 1) == 0
  },
 u,
 {x, 0, 1},
 {y, 0, 1},
 {t, 0, 1}
 ]
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated,

Rick

Comment: Please see lots of related questions using [this search](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Boundary+and+initial+conditions+are+inconsistent).

Comment: The solution does appear fine ... and afaict the boundary conditions are indeed consistent with the initial cond

Comment: @ Szabolcs: thanks for having a look.

Comment: Somewhat irrelevant, have you tried separation of variables? I think you can express the solution using fourrier series ...

Comment: @Spawn1701D: I'm writing my own implementation of FTCS to solve the problem. Separation of variables gives an exact answer, but I wanted to solve it first with Mathematica so that I can compare my output to the result as a cross-check.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The documentation has a full section dedicated to [inconsistent boundary conditions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePDE.html#51169332) in PDEs.

Quoting it,

> Occasionally, `NDSolve` will issue the `NDSolve::ibcinc` message warning
>   about inconsistent boundary conditions when they are actually
>   consistent. This happens due to discretization error in approximating
>   Neumann boundary conditions or any boundary condition that involves a
>   spatial derivative. The reason this happens is that spatial error
>   estimates (see "Spatial Error Estimates") used to determine how many
>   points to discretize with are based on the PDE and the initial
>   condition, but not the boundary conditions. The one-sided finite
>   difference formulas that are used to approximate the boundary
>   conditions also have larger error than a centered formula of the same
>   order, leading to additional discretization error at the boundary.
>   Typically this is not a problem, but it is possible to construct
>   examples where it does occur.

Then an example follows, and a possible solution using the `Method` option's `"TensorProductGrid"` suboption, which we can also apply to your problem.

> When the boundary conditions are consistent, a way to correct this
>   error is to specify that `NDSolve` use a finer spatial discretization.

```
k = 1/(5*(Pi^2));
soln = NDSolve[{
   D[u[x, y, t], t] == k*(D[u[x, y, t], x, x] + D[u[x, y, t], y, y]),
   u[x, y, 0] == y + Cos[Pi*x] Sin[2*Pi*y],
   u[x, 0, t] == 0, 
   u[x, 1, t] == 1, 
   (D[u[x, y, t], x] /. x -> 0) == 0, 
   (D[u[x, y, t], x] /. x -> 1) == 0}, 

  u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, 

  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
               "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 20}}]
```

In this instance `"MinPoints" -> 20` was sufficient to make the problem go away.

---

The same problem was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788728/why-does-this-pde-give-boundary-and-initial-conditions-are-inconsistent-error).  I vaguely remembered it, but it took me a while to find it again ...

Comment: Yep. This kind of quirks may cause madness

Comment: Very nice find. I don't want to admit to how much time I spent last night looking for something in the Advanced Documentation.. regarding that issue. And I even knew, more or less, what to look for (error from discretization and numerical differencing). Oh well.

Comment: @Nasser I don't suppose you have a pdf version of that note of yours available?

Comment: @Daniel It would be really good to have a link to that advanced tutorial on the NDSolve::ibcinc doc page (what you get when you click >>).  I sent a suggestion to support@wolfram half an hour ago, but I don't know if such user suggestions make a difference or not ...

Comment: @Szabolcs I echoed your request to some people involved in NDSolve development. Of course that does not mean it will carry any more weight than your note to Support...

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for the link to the pdf et al.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I filed this as a suggestion against myself.

Comment: @ruebenko I am sorry, I did not know that. It has been said several times that if more users report a bug it will have more weight, so I thought it might be the same for suggestions like this ... it took me quite a bit of time to find your SO post, so I thought it would be really valuable to have a link in the warning message doc page.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks a million; frankly I'm rather embarrassed that I somehow didn't see this in the documentation.

Comment: @Nasser: yep, that's exactly the technique I'm using (learning) in my own implementation of FTCS. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Szabolcs, it's only now that I filed this as a suggestion and because of this post, so there is nothing to be sorry about ;-) no worries.

Comment: @Szabolcs but by searching "inconsistent" on the link you provided, I didn't find such a section dedicated to inconsistent boundary conditions...