# What am I doing wrong when using DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a simple PDE in *Mathematica*. I just can't get *Mathematica* to give me an explicit analytical solution. This is the code that I made and it basically repeats in the output what I have given in the input.

Below are my input and output. What am I doing wrong?

```
pde = D[u[z, t], {t, 1}] + const* D[u[z, t], {z, 2}] == 0
DSolve[pde, u[z, t], {z, t}]
```

> ```
> (u^(0,1))[z,t]+const (u^(2,0))[z,t]==0
> DSolve[(u^(0,1))[z,t]+const (u^(2,0))[z,t]==0,u[z,t],{z,t}]
> ```

Comment: yes, I have, but how do I know that is the wrong syntax? I've never used this part of Mathematica before. The DSolve doc was not very helpful, which I came here.

Comment: actually, I do not get any messages (I thought you meant the output). I'm running Mathematica 9. It does not give me any error messages.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DSolveSecondOrderPDEs.html

Comment: The short answer is that mathematica can't solve the heat equation symbolically. `NDSolve` does though but you have to specify appropriate boundary conditions. i.e. (`const=-1`) `sol = NDSolve[{D[u[z, t], t] -
     D[u[z, t], z, z] == 0, u[-1, t] == t, u[z, 0] == 0}, 
  u, {z, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]`See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20729/2d-heat-equation-inconsistent-boundary-and-initial-conditions) and therein references about the warning.