# Free vibrations of square plate with bi-harmonic equation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am still playing with the wave bi-harmonic equation. My question is very similar to another question I posted few weeks ago on this site ([Solving rectangular plates vibrations wave equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242533/solving-rectangular-plates-vibrations-wave-equation)). I want to visualize the free vibrations of a steel square plate measuring [-a,a;-b,b] and thickness = h (origin = center of the plate).

The issue I met today is the following one : the bi-harmonic equation I am using to NDSolve my problem is working only with some initial conditions parameters sets. With other sets, the computation is never ending (or maybe too long, I don't know) and I get error messages like "DSolve::mxsst: Using maximum number of grid points 100 allowed by the MaxPoints or MinStepSize options for independent variable x." Idem for y and z.

Of course, I searched and found some explanations on this site and some others, but the given solutions never work for me. I think my problem is a method tuning matter in NDSolve. Too hard for me. Help. Thanks in advance.

Below is my code with some helping comments :

```
(* Free vibrations of square plate *)
Remove["Global`*"]; // Quiet
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"]; 
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Ey = SetPrecision[2.078*10^11, Infinity];(*N/m^2*)
\[Nu] = Rationalize[0.317756];(*unitless*)
\[CurlyRho]d = 8166;(*kg/m^3*)
h = 1/1000;
Df = (Ey h^3)/(12 (1 - \[Nu]^2)); a = 1; b = 1;
eqn = {D[u[x, y, t], {x, 4}] + 2 D[u[x, y, t], {x, 2}, {y, 2}] + 
    D[u[x, y, t], {y, 4}] + (\[CurlyRho]d h)/
     Df D[u[x, y, t], {t, 2}] == 
   0}; (* for plates, governing equation = bi-harmonic equation *)
m = 1; n = 2;
ic = {u[x, y, 0] == 
   Cos[m \[Pi] x/a] Cos[n \[Pi] y/b] + 
    Cos[n \[Pi] x/a] Cos[m \[Pi]  y/b], 
  Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][x, y, 0] == 0}; (* initial impulse *)
bc1fe = {Derivative[2, 0, 0][u][-a, y, t] == 0, 
  Derivative[3, 0, 0][u][-a, y, t] == 0, 
  Derivative[2, 0, 0][u][a, y, t] == 0, 
  Derivative[3, 0, 0][u][a, y, t] == 
   0}; (* free edges/ simplified *)
bc2fe = {Derivative[0, 2, 0][u][x, -b, t] == 0, 
  Derivative[0, 3, 0][u][x, -b, t] == 0, 
  Derivative[0, 2, 0][u][x, b, t] == 0, 
  Derivative[0, 3, 0][u][x, b, t] == 
   0}; (* free edges/ simplified *)
numsol = NDSolve[{eqn, ic, bc1fe, bc2fe}, 
  u, {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}, 
  MaxSteps -> 10^6] (* must show the plate behavior in time *)
(* Results visualization *)
uu[x_, y_, t_] := u[x, y, t] /. numsol;
ListAnimate[
 Table[ContourPlot[Evaluate[uu[x, y, t] == 0], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b},
    PlotLabel -> Style[t, 30, Bold]], {t, 0, 1, .05}]]

(* some helping comments:
 *)
(* I also tried the following possibilities without any success : *)
(* numsol=NDSolve[{eqn,ic,bc1fe,bc2fe},u,{x,-a,a},{y,-b,b},{t,0,1},\
Method\[Rule]{"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization"\[Rule]{\
"TensorProductGrid","MaxPoints"\[Rule]101}}]*)

(* numsol=NDSolve[{eqn,ic,bc1fe,bc2fe},u,{x,-a,a},{y,-b,b},{t,0,1},\
Method\[Rule]{"MethodOfLines","TemporalVariable"\[Rule]t,\
"SpatialDiscretization"\[Rule]"FiniteElement"}] *)

(* one important thing : if I replace " Cos[m \[Pi] x/a] Cos[n \[Pi] \
y/b]+Cos[n \[Pi] x/a] Cos[m \[Pi](\y)/b]" by " Cos[1 x] Cos[3 \
y]+Cos[3x] Cos[1y] " the resolution is working well and relatively fast. *)
(* No error messages hapening *)
```

Hereafter is the computation result for Cos[1 x] Cos[3y]+Cos[3x] Cos[1y]. It is also working well for Cos[1 x] Cos[2y]+Cos[2x] Cos[1y]:
[image]

Comment: `Remove["Global\`*"]; // Quiet;
Needs["DifferentialEquations\`NDSolveProblems\`"]; 
Needs["DifferentialEquations\`NDSolveUtilities\`"];
Needs["NDSolve\`FEM\`"];` are redundant. Also, the `FiniteElement` method isn't called in this case, because it cannot handle this type of problem directly at the moment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199369/1871

Comment: @ xzczd : thnak you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues here:

1. Since `ibcinc` warning pops up and you b.c.s all involve derivative, manual adjustion of `"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions"` option discussed in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871) is necessary.
2. Certain silent change (backslide?) has happened on the ODE solver of `NDSolve` in recent versions of *Mathematica*. When the spatial grid is not too dense, *v8.0.4* can handle the problem without adjustion of the ODE solver:

   [image]

   but it's not the case for *v12.2*. One possible work-around I find is to explicitly set `Method -> Adams`.

The following is the fixed code for *v12.2*. `jianshi` is modified from the tools in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134793/1871):

```
showStatus[status_]:=LinkWrite[$ParentLink,
  SetNotebookStatusLine[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[],ToString[status]]];

clearStatus[]:=showStatus[""];
clearStatus[]

jianshi[t_]:=EvaluationMonitor:>showStatus["t = "<>ToString[CForm[t]]]

mol[n:_Integer|{_Integer..}, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

mol[tf:False|True,sf_:Automatic]:={"MethodOfLines",
"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions"->{tf,"ScaleFactor"->sf}}

numsol = NDSolveValue[{eqn, ic, bc1fe, bc2fe}, u, {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, {t, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> Union[mol[25, 4], mol[True, 100], {Method -> Adams}], jianshi[t], 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {61.7096, Null} *)

Table[
 Plot3D[numsol[x, y, t], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, PlotLabel -> Style[t, 30, Bold], 
  PlotRange -> All], {t, 0, 1, .1}] // Partition[#, 5]& // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Don't be worried about the `eerri` and `eerr` warnings, they're merely warnings in this case.

Comment: @ xzczd, thank you for your help. It is very complex for me, but I will try to understand. :)

Comment: @ xzczd : I am impressed !
I applied your solution and the solving time was very very short : {95.3622, Null}.

Comment: @ xzczd : I begin to (try to) understand. 
Your solution is great and multiple. It's amazing. Thank you. I really appreciate. 
The secret of NDSolve is hiding in "Method" settings. May I ask you a question : how did you get all your knowledge about this? Because, personnally I feel it very very tricky, isn't it?

Comment: @Pascal77 The options adjusted in this post are mentioned in the tutorial [_The Numerical Method of Lines_](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html), but I admit it's obscure, I myself dare not say I've fully understood it even now. Things help me most are the answers in this site, for example, I had probably given up using `NDSolve` if I didn't receive user21's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9291/1871) 9 years ago. Knowledge about PDE and core language of _Mathematica_ also helps me to understand the tutorial. The rest is trial & error.

Comment: @ xzczd : you practiced Mathematica for years. Congratulations for your perseverance. I admit that it is fascinating. Personally, I recently discovered Mathematica (november 2020).
I also tried Maple, but I prefer Mathematica. So, my knowledge is very low, and I try to learn through subjects which are near and dear to me, like "Chladni simulation". I began with strange attractors and some electronic circuits modelization. At last, I am trying to understand more deeply Mathematica. In any case, it is a pleasure to discuss with you.