# Never ending story - impossible to export animated gif of a ListAnimate

Tags: plotting, export, animation

I am trying to export an animated GIF file which is the result of a NDSolveValue computation (see below).
The notebook is working fine and fast when I want to make a 3D plot of the solution, for example.
It is the same when I want to plot the following animation (a little bit long but it is OK) :

```
ListAnimate[
 Table[ContourPlot[
   Evaluate[numsol[x, y, t]] == 0, {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style[t, 30, Bold], PlotRange -> All], {t, 0, 
   0.4, .01}]]
```

But when I want to export this animation, it seems to be very very very long. I let Mathematica running 36h, and the result was not still here.

```
Export["nodalanim12.gif", 
 ListAnimate[
  Table[ContourPlot[
    Evaluate[numsol[x, y, t]] == 0, {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, 
    PlotLabel -> Style[t, 30, Bold], PlotRange -> All], {t, 0, 
    0.4, .01}]], "DisplayDurations" -> 10, 
 "AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity]
```

So, am I doing something wrong, or is it MMA which is bugging or maybe this computation is really very complex?
Below is my full code :

```
Ey = SetPrecision[2.078*10^11, Infinity];(*N/m^2*)
\[Nu] = Rationalize[0.317756];(*unitless*)
\[CurlyRho]d = 8166;(*kg/m^3*)
h = 1/1000;
Df = (Ey h^3)/(12 (1 - \[Nu]^2)); a = 1; b = 1;

eqn = {D[u[x, y, t], {x, 4}] + 2 D[u[x, y, t], {x, 2}, {y, 2}] + 
     D[u[x, y, t], {y, 4}] + (\[CurlyRho]d h)/
      Df D[u[x, y, t], {t, 2}] == 
    0}; (* for plates, governing equation = bi-harmonic equation *)

m = 1; n = 2;
ic = {u[x, y, 0] == 
    Cos[m \[Pi] x/a] Cos[n \[Pi] y/b] + 
     Cos[n \[Pi] x/a] Cos[m \[Pi] y/b], 
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][x, y, 0] == 0}; (* initial impulse *)
bc1fe = {Derivative[2, 0, 0][u][-a, y, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[3, 0, 0][u][-a, y, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[2, 0, 0][u][a, y, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[3, 0, 0][u][a, y, t] == 0}; (* free edges/ simplified *)


bc2fe = {Derivative[0, 2, 0][u][x, -b, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 3, 0][u][x, -b, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 2, 0][u][x, b, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 3, 0][u][x, b, t] == 0}; (* free edges/ simplified *)

showStatus[status_] := 
  LinkWrite[$ParentLink, 
   SetNotebookStatusLine[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], 
    ToString[status]]];

clearStatus[] := showStatus[""];
clearStatus[]

jianshi[t_] := 
 EvaluationMonitor :> showStatus["t = " <> ToString[CForm[t]]]

mol[n : _Integer | {_Integer ..}, 
  o_ : "Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

mol[tf : False | True, sf_ : Automatic] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {tf, "ScaleFactor" -> sf}}

numsol = NDSolveValue[{eqn, ic, bc1fe, bc2fe}, 
    u, {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, {t, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> Union[mol[25, 4], mol[True, 100], {Method -> Adams}], 
    jianshi[t], MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {95.0254, Null} *)
(* some warnings happen, but without blocking the computations *)

(* below is the exportation which causes the issue *)
Export["nodalanim12.gif", 
 ListAnimate[
  Table[ContourPlot[
    Evaluate[numsol[x, y, t]] == 0, {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, 
    PlotLabel -> Style[t, 30, Bold], PlotRange -> All], {t, 0, 
    0.4, .01}]], "DisplayDurations" -> 10, 
 "AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity]
```

To precise the context, this animation shows the nodal lines generated by a vibrating plate during 0.4s.
We can show the evolution of the "12" mode vs time.
I made a lot of various calculations such as Plot3D, Table of Plot3D, GIF exports, etc. and all was working fine.
I just got a problem with the export I mentionned above.
So, if somebody would have the kindness to try it and tell me if the same issue is happening?
Thanks in advance.

NB : all the NDSolveValue settings and jianshi usage have been given to me through this link :
[Free vibrations of square plate with bi-harmonic equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246241/free-vibrations-of-square-plate-with-bi-harmonic-equation)

Comment: Usually you would `Export` just the `Table` of plots, not the `ListAnimate`.

Comment: @ Pascal77 as WX said using table its better.
Also i think you have to post your original problem so i try to make a new code or understand your code clearly at least

Comment: @wxffles : thanks. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @Alrubaie : thanks.

Comment: I just tried successfully a GIF export from the following commands :
```
contouranim = 
 ListAnimate[
  Table[ContourPlot[Evaluate[numsol[x, y, t]], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b},
     PlotLabel -> Style[t, 30, Bold], PlotRange -> All], {t, 0, 
    0.9, .1}]]


Export["contouranim12.gif", contouranim]
```
As you can see, it is a simple contourplot, not a nodal lines plot.
The computation is very fast.
As soon as I want to try with ContourPlot==0 (nodal lines, it is too slow).

How to share with you the animated GIF file?

Comment: So, after several trials this afternoon, I confirm that the nodal lines (ContourPlot==0 instead of ContourPlot) export takes a very long time (around 4h) compared to the ContourPlot (only around 5 mn). 
Moreover, I observed that the notebook size has considerably increased (from few Ko to 857 524Ko) after the computation.
This is true for 10 pictures (t=0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ... , 0.9s) animation.

Comment: Therefore, when I want to export an animation with 40 pictures (from t=0, 0.01, 0.02, ..., 0.4, it should take around 16h, but in fact, it seems to bug after a while, and the computation never ends The PC slows down.

Comment: As a preliminary conclusion, I can say that : 
- GIF export command works well with ListAnimate of Table. 
- The computation is fast with ContourPlot and Plot3D.
- The computation becomes very slow with ContourPlot==0 (nodal lines), and I don't understand why.
- For "big" animations, the computation seems to never end, greatly slows down the computer, and increases drastically the size of the notebook.

Comment: NB : The following command line works fine too : Export["contour12.gif", 
 Table[ContourPlot[Evaluate[numsol[x, y, t]], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style[t, 30, Bold], PlotRange -> All], {t, 0, 
   0.9, .1}], "AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity]

Comment: @wxffles : you are right : Export Table of Plots is faster and works fine. In fact, it is useless to export the ListAnimate.

Comment: I don't know if somebody is reading me, but today a new message occured : "
General:The current computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation."
It concerns the following computation : ListAnimate[
 Table[ContourPlot[
   Evaluate[numsol[x, y, t]] == 0, {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style[t, 30, Bold], PlotRange -> All], {t, 0, 
   2, .01}]]

It is not an export this time, but just a 200 points ListAnimate of Table. ...

Comment: ... By contrast, the following calculation was correctly done : ListAnimate[
 Table[ContourPlot[Evaluate[numsol[x, y, t]], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style[t, 30, Bold], PlotRange -> All], {t, 0, 
   2, .01}]]