# Droplet of water-alcohol mixture spreading due to evaporation-caused surface tension gradient

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method, physics, axisymmetry

I am trying to solve a coupled system of PDEs for 2 functions `h[t,r]` and `c[t,r]`, with initial conditions of `h[0,r]` as a normal distribution over `r` and `c[0,r]` set to a fixed value of `0.42` (`c[r,t]` is supposed to always be bounded between `0` and `1`), and fixed boundary values for `h[t,r]` at two points `r = 0.1` and `r = -0.1` (solve domain boundaries). However, when I put the equations and boundary conditions into `NDSolve`, I get the warning

```
Dif = 10^(-5);
cinitial = 0.42;
μ = 0.10;
H = 0.003;
k = 0.001;
boundary = 0.1;
u = H*0.025*D[c[t, r], r]/(μ*c[t, r]);

NDSolve[{k r (1 - c[t, r]) c[t, r] + h[t, r] Dif D[c[t, r], r] + 
    r D[h[t, r], r] Dif D[c[t, r], r] + 
        r h[t, r] Dif D[c[t, r], {r, 2}] == 
      r h[t, r] (D[c[t, r], t] + u D[c[t, r], r]), 
  r D[h[t, r], t] + (r u D[h[t, r], r] + D[u, r]*h[t, r]) == k c[t, r] r, 
    h[0, r] == E^(-(r^2/(2 0.02^2)))/(0.02 10 Sqrt[2 π]), 
    c[0, r] == cinitial, 
    h[t, boundary] == E^(-(boundary^2/(2 0.02^2)))/(
        0.02 10 Sqrt[2 π]), 
    h[t, -boundary] == E^(-(boundary^2/(2 0.02^2)))/(
        0.02 10 Sqrt[2 π])}, {h[t, r], c[t, r]}, {t, 0, 
    10}, {r} ∈ ImplicitRegion[r^2 <= boundary^2, {r}]]
```

> NDSolve::femcnsd: The PDE coefficient `0. -0.001 r c[r]+0.001 r c[r]^2-0.00001 h[r] c'[r]+(0.00075 r h[r] c'[r]^2)/c[r]-0.00001 r c'[r] h'[r]` does not evaluate to a numeric scalar at the coordinate `{-0.1}`; it evaluated to `Indeterminate` instead.

I am really not sure if the cause is my equations or `NDSolve`. I have checked the equations and boundary conditions and was unable to find any errors, and I do not have enough understanding of `NDSolve` and *Mathematica*. Is anyone able to identify the problem? Thanks!

I am using *Mathematica 12*.

---

### Update: background info

The equations describe a droplet of water-alcohol mixture spreading on a surface due to a surface tension gradient which is the result of evaporation (concentration at the edge of droplet decreases faster, surface tension ). The first equation is the diffusion-convection equation for alcohol transport in the droplet, while the second equation is the continuity equation accounting for evaporative loss. `u` is the radial velocity of each fluid element in the drop.

The model is 1D axisymmetric. The initial condition for `h` is defined to be non-zero for all values of `r` to make the solving easier, or an additional moving boundary will have to be added into the equation for the radius of spreading of the droplet. The boundary conditions for `h` are equivalent to setting the bc that the height of the droplet at a radial coordinate approaching infinity to be `0`. I think it is also possible to include the condition `D[c[r,t],r]` at `r = 0.1` and `-0.1` (again at the radial boundaries) to be `0`, if required.

Comment: When I run your code I do not get that output. [![Output of what happens when I run your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8hRN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8hRN.png) I think you have defined variables earlier that has caused this error. Either that or the matrix is singular.

Comment: 1. Which version are you in? 2. Adding background information of the system to the question might help. (Is it from certain literature? Or you deduce it yourself? If so, how you decuce it? ) 3. I suggest using `With` to rewrite the code (to something like `With[{u=u[t,x]},D[u,t]+D[u,x]==0]`) to make it easier to read. 3. The highest differential order of `c` in `r` direction is `2`, and that of `h` is `1`, _usually_ this suggests you need `2` b.c. for `c` and `1` b.c. for `h`, are you sure your b.c.s are correct?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment! Sorry for being unclear in the post, I am very new to StackExchange. I am using Mathematica 12. The equations describe a droplet of water-alcohol mixture spreading on a surface due to a surface tension gradient which is the result of evaporation (concentration at the edge of droplet decreases faster, surface tension ). The first equation is the diffusion-convection equation for alcohol transport in the droplet, while the second equation is the continuity equation accounting for evaporative loss. u is the radial velocity of each fluid element in the drop.

Comment: The model is 1D axisymmetric. The initial condition for h is defined to be non-zero for all values of r to make the solving easier, or an additional moving boundary will have to be added into the equation for the radius of spreading of the droplet. The boundary conditions for h are equivalent to setting the bc that the height of the droplet at a radial coordinate approaching infinity to be 0. I think it is also possible to include the condition D[c[r,t],r] at r = 0.1 and -0.1 (again at the radial boundaries) to be 0, if required

Comment: So, `r` is the radius of cylindrical coordinate?

Comment: Yeah, it is. And the theta and z coordinates are not needed in the equation, so the problem just reduces to one dimension

Comment: James, could you share a literature reference to the model?

Comment: this model is self-derived

Answer (score 11):

At least 3 issues here.

1. You're handling the cylindrical coordinates in an unsual way i.e. setting domain of definition of `r` to $r\in(-\text{boundary},\text{boundary})$. At least in *v12.3.1* this leads to `LinearSolve::parpiv`, which isn't too surprising, because there's a removable singularity at $r=0$. This isn't hard to fix, we just need to change the domain of definition to $r\in(0,\text{boundary})$. (In the code below I have to set the left boundary to a `eps` that's close to `0`. Actually if one chooses `FiniteElement` method
   for spatial discretization, the singularity at $r=0$ will be automatially handled. I don't choose it because the old good `TensorProduct` method is still generally a better choice compared with `FiniteElement` method for time-dependent PDE in regular domain. )
2. After transforming to the required [standard form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158519/1871) of `NDSolve`, `h` term appears at denominator, so `h` that's too close to `0` will cause trouble, we need to modify the i.c. to a milder one. I'll archieve this by adding a small constant (`epsic` below) to the i.c.
3. The troublesome feature of [hyperbolic conservation law](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=conservation+law+user%3A1871) seems to show up in the solution. This might be circumvented by transforming the equation system to something close to conservation form, but it's a bit too hard for me without knowing more about the background info of the system, so I'll simply add artificial viscosity (`vis` below).

The following is the solution.

```
mol[n:_Integer|{_Integer..}, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

Dif = 1/10^5;
cinitial = 0.42;
μ = 0.1;
H = 0.003;
k = 0.001;
boundary = 0.1;
u = (H 0.025 D[c[t, r], r])/(μ c[t, r]);

eps = boundary/100;
vis = 10^-7;
epsic = 10^-2;
hic = 1/(E^(r^2/(2 0.02^2)) (0.02 10 Sqrt[2 π])) + epsic;

With[{h = h[t, r], c = c[t, r]}, 
  eq = {k r (1 - c) c + Dif D[D[c, r] h r, r] == r h (D[c, t] + u D[c, r]), 
        r D[h, t] + (r u D[h, r] + D[u, r] h) == vis D[h, r, r] + k c r};
  ic = {h == hic, c == cinitial} /. t -> 0;
  bc = {{D[c, r] == 0, D[h, r] == 0} /. r -> eps, 
        {D[c, r] == 0, h == hic} /. r -> boundary}];

points = 400; difforder = 2;
{tsth, tstc} = 
  NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, {h, c}, {t, 0, 10}, {r, eps, boundary}, 
   Method -> mol[points, difforder]];
(* Timing:1.4 second *)
```

`NDSolve` spits out `ibcinc` warning, but it's not too big a problem in this case. If you don't like it, change the b.c. `D[h, r] == 0` to `D[h, r] == D[hic, r]` and set a denser grid with e.g. `points = 1000`. If you want to learn more about `ibcinc` warning, read the following posts:

[Boundary condition with spatial derivative is ignored by NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871)

[2D Heat equation: inconsistent boundary and initial conditions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20771/1871)

Finally let's visualize:

```
Plot[#, {r, eps, boundary}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Dashed] & /@ 
  Transpose@Table[{tsth[#, r], tstc[#, r]} &[t], {t, 0, 10, 10/5}] // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

You may adjust `epsic`, `vis`, etc. further to see how the solution changes.

---

If you prefer FEM:

```
molfem[measure_: Automatic] := {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> measure}};

{tsthfem, tstcfem} = 
  NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc[[-1, -1]]}, {h, c}, {t, 0, 10}, {r, 0, boundary}, 
    Method -> molfem[boundary/200]]
(* Timing: 481.155 second *)
```

The discrepency between 2 approaches is ignorable.

I've only explicitly set one b.c. `bc[[-1, -1]]` because the default setting of `FiniteElement` method is zero Neumann value.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much!!! Also, when I run the code I obtain the error "warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent", but it does not seem to affect the solving of the equations. Can you help explain this? Thanks again  : )

Comment: @JamesHe Check the update.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: (+1) I always appreciate your careful distinction pointing out in what cases to use TPG vs. FEM.