# Error in Attempting Moving Boundary Fluid System

Tags: differential-equations, physics, finite-difference-method

Recently I was attempting to solve a moving boundary fluid system on mathematica, which I have managed to convert into a coupled PDE-ODE system based on this helpful reference over [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58596/pde-with-stefan-conditions-a-k-a-variable-boundary).

The equations I am solving are

$$G1[r,t]=m_1 \ln(100*B[r,t])+b1;$$
$$G2[r,t]=m_2 \ln(100*B[r,t])+b2;$$

$$W[r,t]=\frac{p}{q}\frac{\partial (G1[r,t]+G2[r,t])}{\partial r};$$
$$r\frac{\partial N[r,t]}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial N[r,t] W[r,t]}{\partial r}=kB[r,t];$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r N[r,t] \times c \frac{\partial B[r,t]}{\partial r})+k B[r,t] (1-B[r,t])=r N[r,t] (\frac{\partial B[r,t]}{\partial t}+W[r,t] \frac{\partial B[r,t]}{\partial r});$$

Where the maximum value of r, $b[t]$, is solved by the following equation

$$N[b[t],t]\cdot b[t]\cdot(W[b[t],t]-b'[t])=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\pi z[t]^2 b[t]}{4});$$

$$\alpha\cdot W[b[t],t] \cdot (W[b[t],t]-b'[t])+(g_0-G1[b[t],t]-G2[b[t],t])-\frac{q\space z[t] \space b'[t]}{p};$$

So in total there are 4 base variables $N[r,t]$, $B[r,t]$, $b[t]$ and $z[t]$.

The approach I took for this problem is to create normalised variable $x=r/b[t]$ to remove the free boundary and use the [`pdetoode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/dynamic-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation/127997#127997) function to convert all PDEs into a massive ode system that `NDSolve` is able to handle. The code is here:

> ```
> (*Constants and known functions*)
> b1 = 0.0698; m1 = -0.0119; b2 = 0.0526; m2 = -0.0128; g0 = 0.0298;
> q = 3*10^-5; p = 3; k = -0.115; c = 5*10^-4; vis = 10^-4; α = 0.001;
> g1[x_, t_] := m1 Log[100*B[x, t]] + b1;
> g2[x_, t_] := m2 Log[100*B[x, t]] + b2;
> w[x_, t_] := Simplify[(D[g1[r/b[t], t] + g2[r/b[t], t], r]*p/q) /. r -> x b[t]]
>
> (*Defining Equations*)
> With[{n = n[r/b[t], t], B = B[r/b[t], t], w = w[r/b[t], t]},
>  eqnC = Simplify[{(r D[n, t] + D[r*w*n, r] == vis D[ n, r, r] + k*B*r) /. r -> x b[t]}];
>  eqnDC = Simplify[{(D[ r n c D[B, r], r] + k B (1 - B) r == r n (D[B, t] + w D[B, r])) /. r -> x b[t]}];]
>
> eqnRimC = Simplify[{n[1, t] b[t] (w[1, t] - b'[t]) == D[ (π z[t]^2 b[t])/4,t]}];
> eqnRimM = Simplify[{ α n[1, t] w[1, t] (w[1, t] - b'[t]) + (g0 - g1[1, t] - g2[1, t]) - (q z[t] b'[t])/p == 0}];
>
> (*Setting Initial and Boundary Conditions*)
> boundary = 1; σ = 0.2; n0 = 0.4; x0 = 0.001;
> nini[x_] := n0*(-x^2) + n0*(1.05);
> Bini = 0.42;
>
> With[{n = n[x, t], B = B[x, t]},
>  ic = {n == nini[x], B == Bini} /. t -> 0;
>  bc = {D[n, x] == 0, D[B, x] == 0} /. x -> x0]
>
> (*Conversion into ODE system*)
> points = 6;
> domain = {x0, 1};
> grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
> difforder = 4;
> timesolve = 0.03;
>
> tfunc = pdetoode[{n[x, t], B[x, t]}, t, grid, difforder];
> removeredundant = #[[2 ;; -1]] &;
>
> odeqnC = Flatten[eqnC // tfunc] // removeredundant;
> odeqnDC = Flatten[eqnDC // tfunc] // removeredundant;
> odeqnRimC = eqnRimC // tfunc;
> odeqnRimM = eqnRimM // tfunc;
>
> int = removeredundant /@ tfunc@ic;
> int1 = Append[int, {b[t] == 10} /. t -> 0];
> odic = Append[int1, {z[t] == 0} /. t -> 0];
> odbc = bc // tfunc;
>
> (*Solve*)
> time = 0;
> Monitor[{soln, solB, solb, solz} = NDSolveValue[{odeqnC, odeqnDC, odeqnRimC, odeqnRimM, odic, odbc}, {n /@ grid, B /@ grid, b, z}, {t, 0, timesolve}, SolveDelayed -> True, EvaluationMonitor :> (time = t)], time];
> ```

However, when I attempt to solve the equations, `NDSolve` keeps returning me the error that

```
NDSolveValue::ivres: NDSolve has computed initial values that give a zero residual for the differential-algebraic system, but some components are different from those specified. If you need them to be satisfied, giving initial conditions for all dependent variables and their derivatives is recommended.
```

My questions are: why would the system be classified by `NDSolveValue` a differential-algebric system, since every variable has at least one differential term? How could I resolve this issue and obtain my solutions?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

It turns out after increasing the grid to a more reasonable value of `500`, the initial error disappears but the code stops solving at `5*10^-6` according to the `Monitor` function.

**BACKGROUND INFO***

I was interested in the work of [this contributor](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268795/droplet-of-water-alcohol-mixture-spreading-due-to-evaporation-caused-surface-ten) over here but realised that the assumption made were not realistic. I therefore added a rim equation that is described in detail by [Villermaux and Bossa (2010)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/abs/drop-fragmentation-on-impact/126330D40E2B860F87E236EABF9CD941).

In brief I added a cylindrical rim to the edge of the mother droplet, where $z[t]$ is the diameter of the circular cross section of the rim. The first equation describes continuity; the second equation describes conservation of momentum where the effects of surface tension and viscous drag are considered.

Comment: The issue with setting a boundary condition like 'D[B,x]==0/.x-> boundary' is that it implicitly assumes that there is no velocity inflow (due to the definition of w) into the rim, which is quite unlikely. So I thought that if NDsolve is able to figure out the solution without such an assumption it would be a more physically accurate solution.

Comment: Well I think a second order boundary condition holds promise at x = boundary, currently Im setting D[B,x,x], D[n,x,x] ==0 at x-> boundary and it is able to solve past x = 0.1.

Comment: Do you still encounter the `NDSolveValue::ivres` warning after correcting the aforementioned mistakes? If so, please add your version info; if not, please update the question a bit. (In _v12.3.1_ `NDSolve` crashes. )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> … why would the system be classified by `NDSolveValue` a differential-algebric system, since every variable has at least one differential term?

This isn't quite right, because there's no derivative of `t` in `odbc`. Do remember derivatives of `x` have all disappear after discretization.

So the resulting system is a DAE system. As we know, DAE system is generally harder to solve compared with ODE system, and it's clear that, the DAE solver of `NDSolve` is having trouble with your system (to be precise, in *v12.3.1* it crashes), so let's transform the `odbc` to something involving derivative of `t`.

Since the transformation is frequently required when dealing with troublesome DAE system, I've just included a `diffbc` function [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871). (To learn more about why we need `diffbc`, you may want to read [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871). ) With `diffbc`, definition of `odbc` is modified as follows:

```
(* Definition of diffbc isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
With[{sf = 1}, odbc = diffbc[t, sf]@bc // tfunc]
```

To recover the original b.c. from the new `odbc`, proper i.c. is needed, so we modify the definition of `int` to

```
int =tfunc@ic;
```

Avoiding DAE system isn't enough. Trial-and-error suggests the i.c. `z[0] == 0` has lead to a removable singularity at `t==0`, so we modify it to

```
With[{zero = 10^-3}, odic = Append[int1, {z[t] == zero} /. t -> 0];]
```

Still, this isn't the end. With these 3 modifications and `points = 40; difforder=2` (it's not necessary, but you can take away `SolveDelayed -> True` in this case), we

> NDSolveValue::ndsz: At t == 0.015003215536343043`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

…encounter `ndsz` warning around `t == 0.015`. After observing the solution and the original PDE carefully, I believe the stiffness shows up because $N$ is too close to `0` when $t>0.015$, which leads to another removable singularity. Thus I modify `eqnDC` to

```
unitStepExpand = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand@# &;

With[{n = n[r/b[t], t], B = B[r/b[t], t], w = w[r/b[t], t], ϵ = 10^-3},
 eqnDC = Simplify[{(D[r n c D[B, r], r] + k B (1 - B) r == 
        r unitStepExpand@If[n < ϵ, ϵ, n] (D[B, t] + w D[B, r])) /. 
      r -> x b[t]}];]
```

Alternatively, `eqnDC` can be defined as

```
forcepositive[a_List] := With[{ϵ = 10^-3}, If[# < ϵ, ϵ, #] & /@ a];

With[{n = n[r/b[t], t], B = B[r/b[t], t], w = w[r/b[t], t]}, 
 eqnDC = Simplify[{(D[r n c D[B, r], r] + k B (1 - B) r == 
        r forcepositive[n] (D[B, t] + w D[B, r])) /. r -> x b[t]}];]
```

Now even `timesolve = 0.5;` isn't a problem! The following is obtained with `points = 100; difforder=2`:

```
tend = solb["Domain"][[1, -1]];

solBtst = rebuild[solB, grid, 2];
solntst = rebuild[soln, grid, 2];

ListLinePlot[#, PlotRange -> All] & /@ {solb, solz} // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{solBtst[r/solb[t], t], solntst[r/solb[t], t]}, {r, x0 solb[t], solb[t]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, solb[tend]}, {0, 0.5}}], {t, 0, tend}]
```

[image]

### Remark

1. As to the usage of `unitStepExpand`: `PiecewiseExpand` can, as documented, transform a `If[…]` to mathematically equivalent `Piecewise[…]`; `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep `` can transform `Piecewise[…]` to mathematically equivalent combination of `UnitStep[…]`. (This undocumented function is used quite a bit in this site, just have a search if you want to read more examples. ) In other words, `unitStepExpand` is a function that transforms `If[…]` to mathematically equivalent combination of `UnitStep[…]`. I define `unitStepExpand` because `pdetoode` can only handle `Listable` function, but `If` is not, while `UnitStep` is `Listable`. The underlying idea of `forcepositive` is similar. Another related post can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174775/1871).
2. As to the meaning of last argument of `rebuild`: as suggested by the source code of `rebuild`, last argument of rebuild specifies *position of time* i.e. it specifies where the independent variable representing time (in your case, `t`) is placed. By default it's `1` i.e. 1st argument of the generated `InterpolatingFunction[…]` is `t`, but you've chosen the order `…[x, t]` i.e. in your code the function with independent variables is e.g. $B(x,t)$ rather than $B(t,x)$, so we set the last argument of rebuild to `2` to keep the order of independent variables consistent.
3. With `points = 40` a `ListInterpolation::inddp` warning pops up, and `rebuild[…]` fails. It seems that the `DiscontinuityProcessing` of `NDSolve` is triggered in this case. The underlying reason isn't immediately clear to me, but adding `Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}` to `NDSolveValue`, or simply choosing a denser grid e.g. `points = 100` resolves the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! I'll see if I can find any boundary conditions to resolve the stiffness issue :D

Comment: @FLP Aha, I made it. See my update.

Comment: Wow, theres really a lot to learn... @xzczd could you explain what the function unitStepExpand does? I have never saw it before and it seems that a cursory search on Google reveals very little info about it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In addition, why is there a 2 at the end of the rebuild function? I tried the rebuild function normally (without the 2 at the end of the input) and obtained rather weird results.

Comment: When I tried to solve the equation beyond time=0.5, the rebuild function strangely returns me the error that `the point  0.5429501840077648' in dimension 2 is duplicated`.

Comment: @flp I've included the explanations into the answer.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but for some reason the solution field blows up within 0.3s if the variable k is reduced by a magnitude of 10. The concentration field looks okay, but the height field becomes increasingly jagged at the thicker regions.

Comment: @flp With `k = -0.115/10; points=100; difforder=2` the solution looks OK within `timesolve=0.6`, what setting do you choose?

Comment: Never mind, I switched back the value for k and the issue still persists. I edited many parts of the code so something else must have gone wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137299/discussion-between-flp-and-xzczd).